# Processing Dynamically generated rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to process the following input.

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ogwCJx5J03kvFrve1B/BQ5jBlqsGaqP2En7sAe5XcBA=", "contact_attempt_id"=>"79","3"=>"8", "7"=>"22"}
```

I can get the contact_attempt_id and response_code easily. the final two parameters are proving to be elusive.

the key is the database id for a question, while the value is the database id for the answer. I have attempted to loop through the questions looking for the id in the params hash as shown below.

```
questions.each do |q|
  if !params[q.id].nil?
   c = contact_responses.create
   c.question_id = q.id
   c.answer_id = params[q.id]
   c.save
  end
```

however I am not able to get the answer id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `id` from database will be an integer. `params` hash keys are `strings/symbols`(`HashWithIndifferentAccess`)

Change your code to this

```
questions.each do |q|
  unless params[q.id.to_s].blank?
   c = contact_responses.create
   c.question_id = q.id
   c.answer_id = params[q.id.to_s].to_i
   c.save
  end
```

Comment: Still getting the same result. the answer_id is showing in the database as nil. if I hardcode a value in when I create the contact_response i.e. c.answer_id = 40 it saves it to the database.

Comment: Try doing a `to_i` on the `params[q.id.to_s]`. Modified my answer

Comment: adding the to_i just makes it 0 in the database instead of the correct value.

Comment: Only way it would become zero is, when you the `params[q.id.to_s]` is a string that cannot be converted to integer. For eg: `"a".to_i` will be zero. Try logging the values to see if you are actually getting numbers

Comment: logging out just params[q.id.to_s] returns the correct value, trying to convert it to an Int returns 0.

Comment: not sure why doing it in steps works rather than in one shot but it does.